# Is there any way to dynamically add commas to numbers in an input field in a Angular Reactive Form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want to add commas after each 3 digits as the numbers are being entered in the input field.
Using (blur) at the moment, resulting in the commas appearing after removing focus from the input field. I want this process to be smoother.

Comment: Did you consider using a pipe for this purpose?

Comment: I did use a pipe, however it is was not applicable on editable input fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the below solution

```
<div>
    <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" class="example-form">
        <input decimal-mask placeholder="Amount"  formControlName="amount">
</form>
        <div>{{profileForm.value.amount}}</div>
</div>
```

in component.ts

```
  profileForm: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.profileForm = new FormGroup({
      amount: new FormControl("")
    });
  }

@Directive({
  selector: "[decimal-mask]"
})
export class DecimalMask {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, public model: NgControl) {}

  @HostListener("input", ["$event"]) onEvent($event) {
    console.log("keypress: " + $event.keypress);
    var valArray = this.el.nativeElement.value.split(".");
    for (var i = 0; i < valArray.length; ++i) {
      valArray[i] = valArray[i].replace(/\D/g, "");
    }
    let newVal = "";
    if (valArray.length === 0) {
      newVal = "";
    } else {
      let matches = valArray[0].match(/[0-9]{3}/gim);
      if (matches !== null && valArray[0].length > 3) {
        let commaGroups = Array.from(
          Array.from(valArray[0])
            .reverse()
            .join("")
            .match(/[0-9]{3}/gim)
            .join()
        )
          .reverse()
          .join("");
        let replacement = valArray[0].replace(
          commaGroups.replace(/\D/g, ""),
          ""
        );

        newVal =
          (replacement.length > 0 ? replacement + "," : "") + commaGroups;
      } else {
        newVal = valArray[0];
      }

      if (valArray.length > 1) {
        newVal += "." + valArray[1].substring(0, 2);
      }
    }
    // set the new value
    this.model.control.setValue(newVal);
    //this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(newVal);
  }
}
```

working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h7dben?file=app%2Fdecimal-mask.directive.ts)